# Merge different CSVs with different date ranges in a panda dataframe indexed by date and 0 for missing data

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a problem I'm struggling with since a few days, and can't find my way out!

I have a folder with many CSVs, each containing two columns: "date" (YYYY-MM-DD) and "value" (a float). The dates are usually a range of consecutive days (but some days might be missing).

Now each of these CSVs starts from a different date.

I need to merge them into a unique panda dataframe with "date" as index and then several columns like "csv1_value", "csv2_value", "csv3_value" etc. I've done it with 'merge' command on 'date' and that means I do have a panda that contains only the rows where the same "date" was found across all the CSVs.

This is useful because actually some 'dates' in the range might be missing from a file, and in that case I need that date to be deleted from the panda even if it's present in the other files.

BUT I would need to have actually the start of the range in the panda to be the older date I have, and then if that date is missing in the others (because they start later) having the value for that file as 0.

AND any date that is missing from one file range, it should be filled with the latest value (useful to have 0.00 in any file starting later until there's actually some value).

A bit complex, will try an example:

csv1:

```
"2020-01-01","1.01"
"2020-01-02","2.01"
"2020-01-03","3.01"
"2020-01-04","4.01"
"2020-01-05","5.01"
"2020-01-06","6.01"
"2020-01-07","7.01"
"2020-01-08","8.01"
"2020-01-09","9.01"
"2020-01-10","10.01"
```

csv2:

```
"2020-01-04","4.02"
"2020-01-05","5.02"
"2020-01-06","6.02"
"2020-01-08","8.02"
"2020-01-09","9.02"
"2020-01-10","10.02"
```

csv3:

```
"2020-01-03","3.03"
"2020-01-04","4.03"
"2020-01-05","5.03"
"2020-01-06","6.03"
"2020-01-07","7.03"
"2020-01-09","9.03"
"2020-01-10","10.03"
```

resulting Panda should be:

```
"2020-01-01","1.01","0.00","0.00"
"2020-01-02","2.01","0.00","0.00"
"2020-01-03","3.01","0.00","3.03"
"2020-01-04","4.01","4.02","4.03"
"2020-01-05","5.01","5.02","5.03"
"2020-01-06","6.01","6.02","6.03"
"2020-01-07","7.01","6.02","7.03"
"2020-01-08","8.01","8.02","7.03"
"2020-01-09","9.01","9.02","9.03"
"2020-01-10","10.01","10.02","10.03"
```

Anyone has an idea how I could achieve all this? My head is exploding...

Comment: whats the actual date range? do you know it or have access to a business calendar?

Comment: actual date range can really vary, from 10 years to less than one year.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using two outer joins, then fill NA with zeros

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('csv1')
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv2')
df3 = pd.read_csv('csv3')

DF = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='date')
DF = pd.merge(DF, df3, how='outer', on='date')
DF.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, actually implementing the outer merge, and then taking the "df = df.ffill().fillna(0.0)" instruction from previous post, made this working with my actual code implementation.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is designed to cope with arbitrary number of input files
(not only 3, as in the other solution).

Start with reading of your input files, creating a list of
DataFrames, with proper names of the second column:

```
import glob

frames = []
for i, fn in enumerate(glob.glob('Input*.csv'), start=1):
    frames.append(pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=[0], names=['Date', f'csv{i}_value']))
```

Then join them into a single DataFrame:

```
df = frames.pop(0)
while len(frames) > 0:
    df2 = frames.pop(0)
    df = df.join(df2.set_index('Date'), on='Date')
```

For now, from your sample files, you have:

```
        Date  csv1_value  csv2_value  csv3_value
0 2020-01-01        1.01         NaN         NaN
1 2020-01-02        2.01         NaN         NaN
2 2020-01-03        3.01         NaN        3.03
3 2020-01-04        4.01        4.02        4.03
4 2020-01-05        5.01        5.02        5.03
5 2020-01-06        6.01        6.02        6.03
6 2020-01-07        7.01         NaN        7.03
7 2020-01-08        8.01        8.02         NaN
8 2020-01-09        9.01        9.02        9.03
9 2020-01-10       10.01       10.02       10.03
```

And to get the result, run:

```
df = df.ffill().fillna(0.0)
```

The result is:

```
        Date  csv1_value  csv2_value  csv3_value
0 2020-01-01        1.01        0.00        0.00
1 2020-01-02        2.01        0.00        0.00
2 2020-01-03        3.01        0.00        3.03
3 2020-01-04        4.01        4.02        4.03
4 2020-01-05        5.01        5.02        5.03
5 2020-01-06        6.01        6.02        6.03
6 2020-01-07        7.01        6.02        7.03
7 2020-01-08        8.01        8.02        7.03
8 2020-01-09        9.01        9.02        9.03
9 2020-01-10       10.01       10.02       10.03
```

**How to find possible errors**

One of things to check is whether the program finds expected
CSV files.

To check it, run:

```
for i, fn in enumerate(glob.glob('Input*.csv'), start=1):
    print(i, fn)
```

and you should get a list of files found.

Another detail to check is whether your files have names starting
from *Input* and have *csv* extension. Maybe you should change `Input*.csv`
to some other pattern?

Attempt also to run my code **partially**, i.e.:

- first the loop creating the list of DataFrames,
- then check the size of this list, print some of DataFrames
  and invoke *info()* on them (make test printouts),
- after that run the second part of my code (*while* loop).

If some error occus, state in which instruction it occurred.

Comment: This looks VERY promising! Will try and will report back.

Comment: Ok I tried but gives always error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable", apparently on the read_csv. Not sure why, can't find the problem (using Python3). Will keep updated here if I find the problem!

Comment: You should identify what variable is *None*. Maybe *glob* is unable to find any source file?. Another hint: Create 3 CSV files with just the same content you put in your post. Then try my code.

Comment: Ok will try and report back